# Keep the same CSS background even if I don't hover over a menu element 

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

In a dropdown menu I want the menu element keep its background when I hover over the corresponding submenu.

Here is the script:

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" library="css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="styleTableExpansion.css" library="css" />
    <ui:insert name="tohead">content</ui:insert>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function affecter_back(){
            var a = document.getElementById("menuparam")
            a.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
    </script>
</h:head>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="templatemo_menu">
  <ul id="menuDeroulant">
    <li><a href="/impression/faces/vues_admin/acceuil_admin.xhtml" class="current"><span class="home">Acceuil</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/impression/faces/vues_admin/touslesCommandes.xhtml" class="commandes"><span class="commandes">Commandes</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/impression/faces/vues_admin/utilisateurs.xhtml"><span class="users">Utilisateurs</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/impression/faces/vues_admin/newMessage.xhtml"><span class="gallery">Message</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/impression/faces/vues_admin/historiqueMessages.xhtml"><span class="contact">Messages</span></a></li>
    <li>
      <a id="menuparam" href="/impression/faces/vues_admin/historiqueMessages.xhtml"><span class="contact2">Paramétres</span></a>
      <ul class="sousMenu">
        <li><a onmouseover="affecter_back()" href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a onmouseover="affecter_back()" href="#">Graphic design</a></li>
        <li><a onmouseover="affecter_back()" href="#">Development tools</a></li>
        <li><a onmouseover="affecter_back()" href="#">Web design</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>     
</div>
```

But it doesn't do what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: Your title makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: sorry, I m not strong in english

Comment: Also, I think we may need to see how you're achieving the hovering/sub menu to have an idea why the background isn't staying however you want it to be.

Comment: Please provide your CSS styles.